# Как отмасштабировать бесшовный 2D срез 4D шума?

Tags: алгоритм

Ниже алгоритм превращения 4D шума в бесшовный 2D шум, найденный в сети.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таком виде он выдаёт очень крупномасштабный шум. Как его "отдалить" и в целом масштабировать? Многое перепробовал, результат всегда кривой.